# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm try to use "GROUP BY" im MVC

This is my function

```
  private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;


public virtual IList<ShippingByWeightRecord> GetAll()
        {
            string key = SHIPPINGBYWEIGHT_ALL_KEY;
            return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
            {


                var query = from sbw in _sbwRepository.Table
                            group sbw by new
                            {
                                sbw.ShippingMethodId,
                                sbw.From,
                                sbw.To,
                                sbw.ShippingChargeAmount,
                                sbw.RegionId,
                                sbw.ItemRangeId

                            }
                                into grouping
                                select new { grouping.Key,
                                             Id = grouping.Max(sbw => sbw.Id)
                                 };     

                 var records = query.ToList();
                return records;
            });
        }
```

But there is error. How to do it??
This is my sql Command.

```
SELECT     MIN(Id) AS id, ShippingMethodId, [From], [To], ShippingChargeAmount, RegionId, ItemRangeId
FROM         ShippingByWeight
GROUP BY ShippingMethodId, [From], [To], ShippingChargeAmount, RegionId, ItemRangeId
```

I want to write it in MVC?
Do you have any idea???

Comment: It might help if you understood that what you are talking about is not MVC.  It's Linq and Entity Framework.  MVC is irrelevant to your question as MVC is only the technology that provides the web request infrastructure and template rendering.

Comment: Place show the entity ShippingByWeightRecord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create instance of `ShippingByWeightRecord` in `select`. Should be:

```
var query = from sbw in _sbwRepository.Table
                        group sbw by new
                        {
                            sbw.ShippingMethodId,
                            sbw.From,
                            sbw.To,
                            sbw.ShippingChargeAmount,
                            sbw.RegionId,
                            sbw.ItemRangeId

                        }
                            into grouping
                            select new ShippingByWeightRecord {
                                    Id = grouping.Max(sbw => sbw.Id),
                                    ShippingMethodId = grouping.Key.ShippingMethodId,
                                    From = grouping.Key.From,
                                    To = grouping.Key.To,
                                    ShippingChargeAmount = grouping.Key.ShippingChargeAmount,
                                    RegionId = grouping.Key.RegionId,
                                    ItemRangeId = grouping.Key.ItemRangeId  
                             };
```